# Configuration.GetSection returns null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-configuration

I cannot get my `Configuration.GetSection` to return data in `.Value`. I think I implemented all the suggestions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017593/configuration-getsection-always-returns-null), but still can't get it to work.

appsettings.json

```
{
    "AmazonSettings": {
       "BaseUrl": "https://testing.com",
       "ClientID": "123456",
       "ResponseType": "code",
       "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44303/FirstTimeWelcome"
    },
}
```

Startup:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //Set up configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

ConfigurationServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddOptions();

    services.Configure<AmazonSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AmazonSettings"));

    services.AddMvc()
```

AmazonSettings Class:

```
public class AmazonSettings
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
    public string ResponseType { get; set; }

}
```

I'm attempting to access AmazonSettings.Value via IOptions:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly AmazonSettings _amazonSettings;

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.LoginUrl = _amazonSettings.BaseUrl;
        return View("/Pages/Index.cshtml"); ;
    }

    public HomeController(IOptions<AmazonSettings> amazonSettings)
    {
        _amazonSettings = amazonSettings.Value;
    }
```

When I debug, Value is empty:

[image: Debug - Value is empty]

Comment: What you have shown looks accurate according to the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Is that the actual appsetting or just a snippet (minus secure values, of course). Check to make sure that the format of the file is correct. Just throwing out some troubleshooting options.

Comment: @Nkosi never hurts to check! It is just a snippet above. I did confirmed it was formatted correctly - I even removed all other values from appsettings.json (and appsettings.Development.json) besides the "AmazonSettings" section and it still isn't working.. any other ideas?

Comment: Create a new empty project, add the settings and see if it reads it.

Comment: What environment do you see in debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my code in HomeController was never getting hit.

I could get there, and .Value was populated, if I added Routes["home"] above my controller and navigated to localhost/home. I couldn't use Routes[""] however because I'm using Razor pages and this caused an ambiguousActionException.

I then realized I didn't need to use a controller at all with Razor Pages. I could just access my data directly from Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    private readonly AmazonSettings _amazonSettings;
    public string LoginUrl;

    public IndexModel(IOptions<AmazonSettings> amazonSettings)
    {
        _amazonSettings = amazonSettings.Value;
    }
```

With the following access in my Index.cshtml page:

```
<a href=@Model.LoginUrl><h1>@Model.LoginUrl</h1></a>
```

It turns out that when debugging, the .Value returned by GetSection in the Startup code may be null, however it is populated by the time it reaches the IndexModel.